# What is an optimal approach to storing locations that can be queried by distance?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, location

I want to implement a feature where a list of nearby venues can be presented sorted by the distance from user's location. The approach I have right now is to store lat and lon values as floats and to make a query that is looking for +/- values of the location of the user (searching for a square that extends north, south, east and west of the user). Then I do a quick calculation across the resultset determining the distance and sort in my business logic. Now I am approaching this with the perspective of someone who has primarily used relational databases (the app is running MySQL with Hibernate), but is there a better approach (in a different database like Neo4J or with a better column type?)

Also the approach I have has a semi complex workaround for queries at or near 0 lat or 0 lon).

As for my working definition of optimal I'm looking for approaches that are scalable to potentially hundreds of venues in a 10 mile radius and hundreds of thousands of venues in total. To put it another way approximately 1% of SimpleGEO, so if the scale of this problem doesn't require an optimal solution then "you're alright" would also be an interesting answer, though I'd be intested in knowing why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at Lucene/Solr. [Lucene supported location-aware search](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-spatial/) at least since v2.9.

If you're worried about the Lucene complexities, there's [Hibernate Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) which is meant to replicated all database changes across to Lucene transparently.

Comment: I actually have Lucene search implemented already (and with the Hibernate Search too). This will be good to look into. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has native support for geospatial indexes and extensions to the query language to support a lot of different ways of querying your geo spatial documents.

But if you are looking for relation database try PostgreSQL with PostGIS.

Comment: Can you provide any direction of where to start or is there really only one two good options with MongoDB)

Answer (score 1):

Are you look to Hibernate Spatial?

Hibernate Spatial is a generic extension to Hibernate for handling geographic data. And HS have MySQL Provider.

http://www.hibernatespatial.org/